# Racktables/Rackmonkey any usefull rack management Software out there?

Tags: rack

So what is everybody using to manage their racks. We are currently using MediaWiki with quite a lot of custom templates for the servers/racks and virtualised instances.

I looked at [racktables.org](http://racktables.org/) and [Rackmonkey](http://flux.org.uk/projects/rackmonkey/). Both look quite nice but don't quite do what I want. The feature set I'm looking for:

- manages physical Servers

  - manages their components (RAM, CPU, HD, Network)
- locations (Racks)

  - connectivity (contract data like runtime, bandwith, and such)
- manages virtualised servers

  - on which physical server are they
  - which instances do exist
- moving components between it's enclosures (CPU is in a Physical server, phys. server is in a rack) should be easily possible

Comment: Possible dupe: http://serverfault.com/questions/40321/free-tool-for-datacenter-documentation

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en with OCS Inventory

cheers, 
m

Answer (score 6):

Look at [device42](http://www.device42.com).

Comment: Looks interesting, I'm using Racktables right now, but the interface feels like something from 90's.
it's a shame there is so few picture of the interface on there site.

Comment: It's cheap, developer is really helpful, deployed in a DC environment with 500-1000 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.avocent.com/products/datacenter_management.aspx