# free tool for datacenter documentation

Tags: documentation, datacenter

Is there any free tools out there that can help to better document at datacenter, for information like servers in a rack, the group port it is connected to and etc?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Check out RackTables: http://racktables.org/

Answer (score 7):

We're using MediaWiki [1] in our company, works really well for internal documentation. Powers wikipedia as well.

1. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

Comment: Wiki is a good idea.  But for documentation there are better wiki's.  The major issue I've always run into when trying to use MediaWiki for this type of thing is the lack of ACL's.  Making it difficult to restrict access to sensitive documents.  Even Media Wiki's page basically says that access control is not part of their core features and never will be.  There are some plugins that add some of this.  But look at the warning at the top of this page.  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Security_issues_with_authorization_extensions

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nVentory](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/nventory/wiki/Introduction) - Ruby on Rails Datacenter Inventory Manager.

[screeshot_racks http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=194539](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=194539)

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at http://projects.autonomy.net.au/hotwire.  It's a network and DC-aware inventory tool for servers, racks and peripherals.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Windows environment, configuration documentation can be produced automatically and nicely formatted by SYDI - sydiproject.com

Answer (score 1):

Rackmonkey does the basic rack-part ok. (unless you have blades)

If you want to document more you could use GLPI: http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en which has a rack plugin. You can document servers, switches and devices without the plugin.