# Networking and patch panels

Tags: networking

I have started a new job as an IT tech and I'm in charge of the network. I'm looking for some software to help me map out the network wiring. We have numbers on our patch panels and on the wall panels themselves, but is there any good software to help me do this? I spent 20 minutes looking for a panel that didn't even exist.

I was looking to do a floor plan, but I would like to do it with software.

Is there any free software around that can help?

Comment: Shopping questions (product recommendations, free or not) is off topic for this site per the FAQ. Other than that - search the site for "racktables" and you get lots of similar questions from the past, like http://serverfault.com/questions/40321/free-tool-for-datacenter-documentation/49745#49745

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've found, there's no *good* software to do this.  There's some adequate software, [Racktables](http://racktables.org/) springs to mind, but generally I just end up using Google Docs.

Comment: i use google docs also

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly cheap but I've used [SolarWinds lansurveyor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/lansurveyor/) in the past - scans smart / managed switches works out what is connected to each port and their MAC addresses then you can export the visual map to Visio.

Also there's a free trial ;)